# The Shareholder Association doesn't compile

Tags: solidity

I tried the official [Shareholder Association example](https://www.ethereum.org/dao#the-shareholder-association) from ethereum.org in MEW using a private blockchain and I got a warning that prevents contract from compiling.
The warning is ` Variable is declared as a storage pointer. Use an explicit "storage" keyword to silence this warning.
        string description;
        ^----------------^
,

`

If I change it to *string storage descripton* I get another error:

```
 Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity'
    string storage description;
           ^
```

I am using the latest version of MEW.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

[image]